# Where in Tarkov can I find the WZ Wallet?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

Fence [has sent me to collect](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/Collector) a few "hard to find" items, most of which were not too hard to guess where they would be found. Except one. The **[WZ Wallet](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/WZ_Wallet)**. The description says

> The same as any simple wallet, but fancier.

I found the food items together with other foodstuff, the antiques in buried caches and the figurines in safe boxes. But the wallet is puzzling me, there does not seem to be an obvious place for it to be found at, except maybe safe boxes (because it is about valuables), but I think I tried enough of those to rule out that option.

I am starting to wonder whether I may be missing some knowledge about the person - *WillerZ* - the item is dedicated to that is required to  understand where or how the item is at least somewhat likely to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moonshine [Scav Case](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/Hideout) has a higher probability of streamer items and this is one place you can get the WZ Wallet, its not consistent but thankfully it also gives most of the other items you are asked for in this particular task.

It is also worth noting that in the 12.12 update, the WZ wallet became slightly more common in the dorms marked room and will tend to have keycards in it, making it better than before for farming the WZ Wallet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, because others reported to have found one using these methods:

1. ***Marked* spots** generally have a higher probability of rare items

   - rooms locked with *"marked" keys*  (3 on *Reserve*, 1 on *Customs*)
   - other places recognizable from *candle* decoration (2 on *Woods*, one in Resort at *Shoreline*)
2. A few mechanics provide a chance **randomly get *any* tradable item**, notably

   - below the "giving tree" near the medical bag at *Customs* old gas station
   - on the table inside said old gas station
   - backpacks spawning in the open, as well as those
   - > backpacks carried by *Cultist* NPCs
   - quest rewards from daily of weekly operational tasks

Both methods, while in the realm of possibility, appear to be a [bit of a grind](https://www.reddit.com/r/EscapefromTarkov/comments/ptm62u/).

My still unproven original was to hope the ["fancier" wallet](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/WZ_Wallet) occasionally appears in place of [the less fancy wallet](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/Simple_wallet). Which can be lifted from Scavs pockets and certain shelves.. among about 30 such wallet finds a few had *fancy* contents, but none the outer appearance.